# MySQL SELECT best-fit record based on optional NULL values

Tags: mysql, select, null

Please refer to this SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9db4f

Table 'rate' stores hourly chargeout rates for job roles, with the option to store varying rates for a role based on the client company, group (a 'group' is just a division of a company) and client contact.

Rates can also vary over time.

I'd like to select the single most recent, best-fit rate for a given combination of role, company, group and contact. It should try to match, in this order:

1. client_contact, client_group, client_company and role
2. client_group, client_company and role
3. client_company and role
4. just role

For example: I'm looking for a rate matching role ID 3, company ID 3 and client ID 4.

There isn't a record matching all of those, so it should look for one matching just role ID 3 and company ID 3. (The other fields - client_contact and client_group - must be NULL). There are two of those: row ID's 2 and 3. It should select row ID 3, as it has the most recent 'date_from' date.

Another example: I'm looking for a rate matching role ID 3, and company ID 25.
There isn't one of those either so it should look for one matching just role ID 3, and NULLs for all the other values. There's only one matching row: number 1.

The query on the current SQLFiddle does the 'fetch the most recent' bit, but I'm stuck as to getting it to match optional columns if they're present.

Halp :(

Edit: oops, it looks like SQLFiddle only saves the schema, not the query. This is what I've got:

```
SELECT 
  rate.*
FROM
  rate
LEFT JOIN rate AS newest ON (
  rate.role = newest.role
  AND COALESCE(rate.client_company, 1) = COALESCE(newest.client_company, 1)
  AND COALESCE(rate.client_group, 1) = COALESCE(newest.client_group, 1)
  AND COALESCE(rate.client_contact, 1) = COALESCE(newest.client_contact, 1)
  AND newest.date_from > rate.date_from
)
WHERE newest.id IS NULL
```

Comment: SQL Fiddle saves the query too, you just have to copy the URL after you hit "Run Query": http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9db4f/10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took this to mean that for each rate record, you want the most recent rate that matches.  The following works on the given data, but the real answer comes after this.

```
select rate.*,
       rmax.hourly_rate,
       rmax.maxdate
from rate join
     (select rmax.*, forhr.hourly_rate
      from (select role, client_company, client_group, client_contact, MAX(date_from) as maxdate
            from rate
            group by role, client_contact, client_group, client_company, role with rollup
           ) rmax join
           rate forhr
           on coalesce(rmax.role, '') = coalesce(forhr.role, '') and
              coalesce(rmax.client_company , '') = coalesce(forhr.client_company, '') and
              coalesce(rmax.client_contact, '') = coalesce(forhr.client_contact, '') and
              coalesce(rmax.client_group, '') = coalesce(forhr.client_group, '') and
              rmax.maxdate = forhr.date_from
     ) rmax
     on coalesce(rmax.role, '') = coalesce(rate.role, '') and
        coalesce(rmax.client_company , '') = coalesce(rate.client_company, '') and
        coalesce(rmax.client_contact, '') = coalesce(rate.client_contact, '') and
        coalesce(rmax.client_group, '') = coalesce(rate.client_group, '')
```

The inner query is just to get the most recent rate associated with the date.  The outer query does the match to each record in the rate table.

I'm not sure what I was thinking above; I think I was interrupted in my thought processes.  I think the best way to approach this is with a correlated subquery.  The following gets the max rate.  You can use the same approach to get the id and additional information:

```
select r.*,
       (select hourly_rate
        from rates r2
        where coalesce(r.role, '') = coalesce(r2.role, '') and
              coalesce(r.client_company , '') = coalesce(r2.client_company, '') and
              coalesce(r.client_contact, '') = coalesce(r2.client_contact, '') and
              coalesce(r.client_group, '') = coalesce(r2.client_group, '')
        order by (case when r2.client_contact is not null then 1
                       when r2.client_group is not null then 2
                       when r2.client_company is not null then 3
                       when r2.role is not null then 4
                       else 5
                  end),
                 date_from desc
        limit 1
       ) as most_recent_hourly_rate
from rates r
```

This uses a correlated subquery to get the row that has the most matches.  The key is the `order by` clause, which orders by the "most matched" field to the "least matched", and then by date.  In this case, it pulls the hourly rate.  In practice, I would pull the id and join back to rates to get the rate and other information (such as the date).

In the given form, it assumes the data in `rates` is structured as you say and that you don't have rows with, say, client_group and role, but not the other fields.

Comment: This *looks* like it'll do the job. However, I don't understand how/where it's doing the "for a given combination of role, company, group and contact" bit. I need to pass it those paramaters, and have it return me a single row that best fits them. At the moment it's returning all rows.

Answer (score 2):

I would approach it like this.

Asssuming you are looking for:

```
client_contact = 5
client_group= 3
client_company= 3
role = 3
```

Query:

```
select *
from rate
where ifnull(client_contact, 5) = 5
    and ifnull(client_group, 3) = 3 
    and ifnull(client_company, 3) = 3 
    and ifnull(role, 3) = 3
order by case
    when client_contact = 5 and client_group = 3 and client_company = 3 and role = 3
      then 1
    when client_contact is null and client_group = 3 and client_company = 3 and role = 3
      then 2
    when client_contact is null and client_group is null and client_company = 3 and role = 3
      then 3
    when client_contact is null and client_group is null and client_company is null and role = 3
      then 4
end, date_from desc
limit 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9db4f/13)

Comment: This solves the specific problem of finding the rate for client 5, group 3, company 3 and role 3. How would it solve the problem of fetching a rate for *any given* combination of client, group, company and role, without adding a new CASE statement for each combination?

Comment: @Wintermute Do you mean how would you search for multiple combinations at once?

Comment: Otherwise you just parameterize it, or use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

On your returned set, I would try to assign a rank based on the optional column, so higher the rank, closest the match and then will get the record with Max rank .... (Tested on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9db4f))

Expanding your query:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM
(
    SELECT
      rate.*,
      ((CASE WHEN COALESCE(rate.client_company, 1) = COALESCE(newest.client_company, 1)
                       AND rate.client_company = 25  THEN 1
             ELSE 0 END) +
       (CASE WHEN COALESCE(rate.client_group, 1) = COALESCE(newest.client_group, 1)
                      AND rate.client_group = NULL THEN 1
             ELSE 0 END) +
       (CASE WHEN COALESCE(rate.client_contact, 1) = COALESCE(newest.client_contact, 1)
                      AND rate.client_contact = NULL THEN 1
             ELSE 0 END)) AS RANK
      FROM
        rate
      LEFT JOIN rate AS newest
        ON rate.role = newest.role
       AND COALESCE(rate.client_company, 1) = COALESCE(newest.client_company, 1)
       AND COALESCE(rate.client_group, 1) = COALESCE(newest.client_group, 1)
       AND COALESCE(rate.client_contact, 1) = COALESCE(newest.client_contact, 1)
       AND newest.date_from > rate.date_from
     WHERE newest.id IS NULL
       AND rate.role = 3
) T
HAVING T.Rank = MAX(T.Rank)
```

Please Note:
  In code where we have rate.client_company = 25, 25 should be replaced with input parameter of Company Code.
  In code where we have rate.client_group = NULL, NULL should be replaced with input parameter of Client Group Id
  In code where we have rate.client_contact = NULL, NULL should be replaced with input parameter of ClientContactId
  IN Code where we have rate.role = 3, 3 should be replaced with input parameter of RoleId.

I tried to declare variables in SQl Fiddle but was unable to do so, so i hardcoded the above values...